# Creating a CSV with manipulated data from another CSV

Tags: c, csv, pointers, struct

So I have data from a CSV, which I've added into a Struct array (below). I now want to output the min and max of those values in another CSV file.

```
typedef struct {
    double xvalue;
    double yvalue;
    double uvalue;
    double vvalue;
} flow_data;
```

I've printed out these values, which all works but instead I want to output it into a CSV file, exactly how it is outputted here. How would I go about doing that? Tell me more information is needed about the program.

```
flow_data* z = &dataset[ivalueofmaxu];
printf("%.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->uvalue, z->vvalue);

z = &dataset[ivalueofminu];
printf("%.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->uvalue, z->vvalue);

z = &dataset[ivalueofmaxv];
printf("%.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->uvalue, z->vvalue);

z = &dataset[ivalueofminv];
printf("%.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->uvalue, z->vvalue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fprintf` to print into file.
Syntax is

```
int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...)
```

Where `*stream` is file stream. Use `fopen` to get the file stream as below.

```
FILE * fp;

fp = fopen ("someother.csv", "w+");

flow_data* z = &dataset[ivalueofmaxu];
fprintf(fp , "%.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->uvalue, z->vvalue);

z = &dataset[ivalueofminu];
fprintf(fp, "%.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->uvalue, z->vvalue);

z = &dataset[ivalueofmaxv];
fprintf(fp, "%.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->uvalue, z->vvalue);

z = &dataset[ivalueofminv];
fprintf(fp, "%.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->uvalue, z->vvalue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `fprintf` instead of `printf` (`<stdio.h>` header).

But first you need to open desired file in write mode:

```
FILE * fp = fopen("testfile.csv", "w");
```

Then using pointer to previously opened file you can easily write your values to it:

```
flow_data* z = &dataset[ivalueofmaxu];
fprintf(fp, "%.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->uvalue, z->vvalue);

z = &dataset[ivalueofminu];
fprintf(fp, "%.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->uvalue, z->vvalue);

z = &dataset[ivalueofmaxv];
fprintf(fp, "%.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->uvalue, z->vvalue);

z = &dataset[ivalueofminv];
fprintf(fp, "%.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->uvalue, z->vvalue);
fclose(fp); // remember to close it after you are done
```

As you can see the main difference is additional argument with pointer to FILE.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write your output into a new CSV file, there is nothing special about writing data into CSV files, you just need to keep syntax (accepted separator is the comma ',' not the semi-colon ';') and you should be fine.
I would suggest you to use `fprintf` to do that, there is an example ready.
[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/)